# lastInsertId() returns empty string

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Why?

```
try{

    $st = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO thetable (a,b) VALUES (?,?)");
    $st->execute(array(5,5));

    $id = $this->lastInsertId();

    echo $id;            // nothing 
    echo gettype($id);   // string

    return $id;          // and I get NULL returned, this is even weirder...

}catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e);
    return false;
}
```

The table has an id column which has auto increment. Why don't I get the id value?

Comment: Post the lastInsertId function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: do the values actually get inserted?

Comment: If the values didn't get inserted see if $st->execute is performing right.

Comment: yes, the db gets updated

Comment: var_dump($id); is usually the most useful for debugging.

Comment: ok I found out why I get null - it's because this code is in a function and I'm calling the wrapper of this function but forgot to return the value in the wrapper :) But I still dont get the id, it's just a empty string now

Comment: Do you mean that `$this` is acting as a PDO object?

Comment: yes, it's a class i extended from pdo

Comment: It is weird. Have you tried to switch (just to **test** first) and instead of using `->execute` use `->query` instead, then see if lastInsertId works?

Comment: Alex, do you mind to share the entire class please because I'm too lazy to replicate the code?

Comment: k, this might be silly, but does your table have an id that autoincrements?

Comment: yes I do, it's the 'id' field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
$this->lastInsertId();
```

have you tried

```
$st->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: `lastInsertId()` is a method of the PDO object, not of PDOStatement

Answer (score 5):

ok, just found out why. I'm posting this as an answer because most likely there will be others who will run in the same problem :D

So `PDO::lastInsertId();` will be empty is you call it after `PDO::commit()`, which I did because I was using atomic transactions. It needs to be called after execute()...

Note that I don't have beginTransaction and commit() in the code above so the code in my question is actually correct, the problem was home :)

Comment: wow, thanks, that would have driven me crazy for a few days 0_0

Comment: that wasn't something specified in your question :)

Comment: yes, sorry.. I didn't think it was relevant to post the exact code